# nginx +PHP 5.6.30 / FPM/FastCGI using set_time_limit(x) in a script causing fatal error

Tags: php, nginx, centos

Whenever there is `set_time_limit(x)` in PHP script, it causes PHP fatal error after 30s of max execution time.

Any idea what might be wrong? I am not using `set_time_limit()` function, but many WordPress plugins and WordPress upgrade core PHP files do, causing me a headache.

```
<?php
set_time_limit(300);
echo 'test';
?>
```

> Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded in /var/www/html/test.php on line 2

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The cause of the problem is slowness. Increase the parameter to something bigger temporarily, or comment out those lines altogether. When you have finished with this, optimize your project, so a request will not take so long and when you are comfortable with the performance, you can put back the time limits. Also, it might be worth to ask the authors of the plugins whether they will release a version where you can enable/disable this feature or set the time limit yourself.

Comment: The thing is that using function `set_time_limit()` is causing the timeout error. Even when a PHP scripts execution time is 1ms and I use `set_time_limit()` it will cause Fatal Error after 30s.